# update unix timestamps (in ms) with their human-readable equivalents in a JSON value

Tags: json, date, sed, jq, epoch

I have a file with some epoch date (with millisecondes) coded inside.
I would like to parse the file to convert the epoch into human readable date format.

This is what the content of the file looks like :

```
{
    "Date": "1555095683495",
    "read": "1"
  },
{
    "Date": "1555578329532",
    "read": "1"
  },
```

I tried to convert the date by using the commande *date* with the use into *sed* but dont get it working correctly.
=> case 1 : the epoch date is replaced but date is not executed.

```
$ cat myfile.json | sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{13,\}\)/date -d @\1/g"*
  {
    "Date": "date -d @1555095683495",
    "read": "1"
  },
  {
    "Date": "date -d @1555578329532",
    "read": "1"
  }
```

==> case 2: epoch date is replace by a executed command of date but it take @1 as value and not the good one...

```
$cat myfile.txt | sed -e "s/[0-9]\{13,\}/$(date -d @\1)/g"
  {
    "Date": "jeu 01 jan 1970 01:00:01 CET",
    "read": "1"
  },
  {
    "Date": "jeu 01 jan 1970 01:00:01 CET",
    "read": "1"
  }
```

Any help appreciated to get it working correctly.
I also presume the value has to be divided by 1000 to get the milliseconds away but dont see how to get both working.

Comment: Are you allowed to use JSON parser `jq` for this? It is a JSON syntax aware parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQ, convert each timestamp to a number, divide the result by 1000 to get a value that date manipulation builtins could understand, and feed it to `strflocaltime` to get a human-readable date string.

```
$ jq '.[].Date |= (tonumber / 1000 | strflocaltime("%c %Z"))' file
[
  {
    "Date": "Fri Apr 12 22:01:23 2019 +03",
    "read": "1"
  },
  {
    "Date": "Thu Apr 18 12:05:29 2019 +03",
    "read": "1"
  }
]
```